# Solve a particular differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am quite new to differential equations and I have to solve the following $a(t)+b(t)C(t)+s a(t)C'(t)=0$, where $s$ is some constant. I read about differential equations and at this moment my main difficulty is that $C'(t)$ is multiplied by $s a(t)$ (the examples of differential equations I have seen so far have $s a(t)=1$). Does anyone have a hint about this equation (maybe it turns out to be a "famous" equation and I am not aware about it) and how to solve it?

Comment: How about dividing the equation by $sa(t)$? Then it's the same as your exemples

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have already did this, but I get a wrong result. I divided by $sa(t)$ and I got the following equation $s^{-1}+\frac{b(t)C(t)}{sa(t)}+C'(t)=0$. Then, assuming that $K'(t)=\frac{b(t)}{sa(t)}$ I multiplied the equation by $\exp{K(t)}$, obtaining $\exp{K(t)}\frac{b(t)C(t)}{sa(t)}+\exp{K(t)}C'(t)=\exp{K(t)}s^{-1}$. Since on the right-hand side there is a constant that multiplies $\exp K(t)$, I get a nice result, i.e. $C(t)=-a(t)/b(t)$, which is, regrettably, wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you did in your comment is correct up to (except a negative sign)

$$\exp{K(t)}\frac{b(t)C(t)}{sa(t)}+\exp{K(t)}C'(t)=-\exp{K(t)}s^{-1}$$

After that
$$\left(\exp{K(t)}C(t)\right)'=-\exp{K(t)}s^{-1}$$

Integrate both sides
$$\exp{K(t)}C(t)=-s^{-1}\int\exp{K(t)}\,dt+D\\
C(t)=-s^{-1}\exp{(-K(t))}\int\exp{K(t)}\,dt+D\exp{(-K(t))}$$
where $D$ is a constant.